# C# stopwatch bug?

Tags: c#, stopwatch

When I make an array containing methods, stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds always returns 0.

Example:

```
int[] methods = {method1(), method2()};

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
int val = methods[1];
sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("It took {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
// Output: "It took 0 ms"
```

When i just call the method directly, then the stopwatch works properly:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
method1();
sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("It took {0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
// Output: "It took x ms"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Actual main code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch t = new Stopwatch();
            Func<int>[] problems = new Func<int>[] { problem5, problem6 };


            for (int i = 0; i < problems.Length; i++)
            {
                t.Restart();
                Console.WriteLine("Solution to {0} is: {1}", problems[i].Method.Name , problems[i]());
                t.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("It took {0} ms ", t.ElapsedMilliseconds);


            }

            Console.ReadKey();


        }
```

Output:
[image: http://puu.sh/3Znwd.png]

Comment: Why do you call the Stopwatch `sw` and then look at the value of `t`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int[] methods = new[] { method1(), method2() };
```

This one calls directly `method1()` and `method2()` BEFORE your `Stopwatch`!

Try

```
Func<int>[] methods = new Func<int>[] { method1, method2 };

t.start();
methods[1]();
```

Example

```
Func<int>[] methods = new Func<int>[] { method1, method2 };

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

for(int i = 0; i < methods.Length; i++)
{
    sw.Restart(); // or sw.Reset(); sw.Start();
    methods[i]();
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("{0} took {1} ms", allMethods[i].Method.Name, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);      
}
```

Comment: But don't i call method1() again when i do methods[0]; ?

Comment: @MeesterPatat - No, in your example you only get the value at `methods[0]` which is the value that was returned by `method1` when you first initialized the array.

Comment: @MeesterPatat I'll add that it doesn't even compile. At the `methods[1]` it writes to me: `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

Comment: All my methods return a integer, so Action[] gives me an error.

Comment: @xanatos The methods should return an integer, because the array is integer.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Only 1 thing: sw.ElapsedMilliseconds still doesn't work properly. It seems that when i do allMethods[i](); instead of only executing method i, it executes all methods in allMethods. So the output is like this: method1 took 500 ms, method2 took 0 ms, method3 took 0 ms. While in fact all methods together took 500 ms. I solved it by just doing the stopwatch stuff in the methods, but it's probably not the best solution.

Comment: @MeesterPatat Look at the example. `Stopwatch.Stop()` doesn't reset the timer, so `Stopwatch.Stop(); Stopwatch.Start()` will restart the timer from where it was stopped. You have to `Reset()` or `Restart()` the timer.

Comment: Ok, i added my actual code and the output in the opening post. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @MeesterPatat It's `methods[i].Method.Name, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds` not `methods[i].Method.Name, t.ElapsedMilliseconds` (`sw` instead of `t`). Ideone: http://ideone.com/zZFYE7 note that Mono doesn't support the Restart(), so I did the Reset(); Start();

Comment: In the edit, my Stopwatch is actually called t. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @MeesterPatat Perhaps `method2()` is too much fast! Try using the `ElapsedTicks` or adding a `Thread.Sleep(100)`; to `method2()`

Comment: @xanatos Thanks, the problem was: I had commented out method2 and forgot doing it, so it took 0 ms to execute, because of this I got confused.

Comment: I like 'your' example ;)

Comment: @keyboardP Parallel thinking :-)

Comment: @keyboardP But if you look at the history, you'll see that my first version had an error that wasn't in yours. I had copied the t from the code of the OP.

Comment: @xanatos - Nah, it's fine :) It's the correct answer and you helped him with the comments which I didn't do.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're trying to benchmark a group of methods that return ints. You can do something like this

```
Func<int>[] allMethods = new Func<int>[] { method1, method2 };

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
for(int i =0; i < allMethods.Length; i++)
{
    sw.Restart(); 
    allMethods[i]();
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("{0} took {1} ms", allMethods[i].Method.Name, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);      
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Only 1 thing: sw.ElapsedMilliseconds still doesn't work properly. It seems that when i do allMethods[i](); instead of only executing method i, it executes all methods in allMethods. So the output is like this: method1 took 500 ms, method2 took 0 ms, method3 took 0 ms. While in fact all methods together took 500 ms. I solved it by just doing the stopwatch stuff in the methods, but it's probably not the best solution.

Comment: That shouldn't happen and I can't reproduce the problem, there must be something else in your code. How do you know that all three took 500ms in total? Are you sure the stopwatch code in your methods aren't messing with the results?

Comment: Ok, i added my actual code and the output in the opening post. What am i doing wrong?